# using sed to search and replace the first word(string is divide by whitespace) in a string

Tags: string, sed

An input string: `"a-random_name /this/is/a/path_to-file 0"`
An output string: `"arandomname /this/is/a/path_to-file 0"`
using sed only replace the first word. word is a random string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple awk method

```
awk  '{gsub(/-|_/,"",$1); print}' <<< '"a-random_name /this/is/a/path_to-file 0"'
```

**Output :**

```
"arandomname /this/is/a/path_to-file 0"
```

**Explanation:**

Extract first column based on default space delimiter and remove `-` and `_` using `gsub` function

**`Sed` version :**

I am not sure this is the effective method or not but it will help you

```
sed -e 's/-\|_//1' -e  's/-\|_//1' <<< '"a-random_name /this/is/a/path_to-file 0"'
```

Comment: this works, but if there is an alternate solution using sed?

Comment: The sed command will only work with 2 occurrences of `_` or `-`.

Comment: @SLePort, Yeah I know , But I am referring `awk` ,but `sed` I tried

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed ':a;s/^\([^-_ ]*\)[-_]/\1/;ta;' file
```